# MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider does not respect [Authenticate("microsoftgraph")] attribute

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, authorization, servicestack

We have implemented the MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider and it is all set up correctly as we have added an endpoint to output the authorized user's credentials using the following:

```
 if (!IsAuthenticated) return null;
 var session = this.Request.GetSession(true);
 return session.ToJson();
```

This outputs my user, with the provider as microsoftgraph. Great, everything as expected.

However, when we add the authorization attribute:

```
 [Authenticate("microsoftgraph")]
```

It returns a 401 and acts as if we are not logged in at all. All ss-id and ss-pid are sent in headers correctly, but it still returns a 401.

However, elsewhere in the system, we are using this same method to limit to API key auths

```
  [Authenticate("apikey")]
```

We currently have 3 IAuthProviders loaded into the API.

Is there an issue in the provider itself or is there a different methodology behind limiting a service to microsfoftgraph provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an Auth Provider name, e.g:

```
[Authenticate("microsoftgraph")]
```

It tells ServiceStack to check with that registered AuthProvider to determine whether it thinks user is Authenticated which it does by calling its `IsAuthorized()` method, `MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider` doesn't have one defined so it uses its base [OAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/633ecf3af2a56297e41d80965afda651985450a3/src/ServiceStack/Auth/OAuthProvider.cs#L69-L77) implementation:

```
public override bool IsAuthorized(IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Authenticate request = null)
{
    if (request != null)
    {
        if (!LoginMatchesSession(session, request.UserName)) return false;
    }

    return session != null && session.IsAuthenticated && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokens?.AccessTokenSecret);
}
```

You can override this behavior by either overriding the AuthProvider and implementing `IsAuthorized` or by overriding your [Custom UserSession](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#using-typed-sessions-in-servicestack) and overriding `IsAuthorized(provider)`, e.g:

```
public class MyUserSession : AuthUserSession
{
    public override bool IsAuthorized(string provider)
    {
        if (provider == MicrosoftGraphAuthProvider.Name)
            return IsAuthenticated && AuthProvider == provider;
        return base.IsAuthorized(provider);
    }
}
```